# Нужно добавить возможность оставлять комментарии к статьям

Tags: html, css, python, django

хочу чтобы к статьям можно было добавлять комментарии.
я немного сам пытался но если че можете все удалить и сами написать как вам угодно

views.py

```
from RapterGames.news.forms import CommentsForm
from .models import Articles


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = "news/posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'articles_list'


    def get_queryset(self ):
        return Articles.objects.all()

    def comment(request):
        form = CommentsForm(request.POST)

        comment = request.POST['comment']

        context = {'form': form,
                   'comment': comment,
                   }

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return redirect('registration/login.html')

        form = CommentsForm()
        context = {'form': form
                   }

        return render(request, 'registration/registred.html', context)


def aboutUs(request):
    return render(request,'news/aboutUs.html')
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from . models import Articles

urlpatterns=[
    path('', ListView.as_view(queryset=Articles.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:20],template_name="news/posts.html")),
    path('<int:pk>/', DetailView.as_view(model=Articles, template_name="news/post.html")),
    path('aboutUs', views.aboutUs, name='aboutUs')
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, Form


class CommentsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Form
        fields = ('comenmt')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms

# Create your models here.

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

posts.html

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for article in articles_list  %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.img.url }}"/></p>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
          <a href="/news/{{article.id}}"> <h1> {{article.title}} </h1> </a>
          <h3 align="right">{{article.date|date:"d-m-Y"}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

post.html

```
{% block content %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1 class=" text-info">{{articles.title}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <p> {{articles.post|safe|linebreaks}}  </p>
            <h3 align="right" class=" text-info"> Опубликованно: {{articles.date|date:"d-m-Y в H:i"}}</h3>
      </div>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основное отличие комментария (абстрактно) от других моделей в том, что мы не можем чётко определить его взаимосвязь с конкретной моделью, так как комментировать можно очень много всего.
Мы бы могли создать несколько моделей комментария на всё, что можно комментировать, но в Django есть более изящное решение.

Мы воспользуемся `GenericRelation`. Это позволит нам привязывать комментарий к любой из указанных моделей. Я для примера создам модель `Post`.

***models.py:***

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey


class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=4096)


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=4096)
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
```

Для того чтобы создать комментарий мы можем сделать следующее:

```py
obj_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(post)
Comment.objects.create(content_type=obj_type, object_id=post.id, author=user)
```

Получить комментарии к конкретному посту можно так:

```py
Comment.objects.filter(object_id=post.id)
```

`post` - экземпляр модели `Post`.
`user` - экземпляр модели `User` (например, `request.user` в представлении).