# Есть ли какая нибудь готовая библиотека комментариев для django 3

Tags: python, django, поиск-библиотек

Изначально пробовал djnago comments, но оказалось, что она уже не поддерживается. Есть ли замена django.contrib.comments для комментариев на django 3 или как сделать возможность добавления комментариев?

Всё расписывать не нужно. Просто скиньте ссылку или название, я сам прочитаю.

Comment: Сделайте сами, это довольно просто. Я уже отвечал на подобный вопрос, вот мой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/992176/339283)

Comment: А что, уже вышло django 3? Вообще, если вы хотите уже готовое, может вам посмотреть в сторону django-cms? Там многое уже есть из коробки

Comment: Зачем готовое, если их создавать 5 минут...

Comment: @Александр посмотрите https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django Версии и хронология их выхода . (The latest official version is 3.1.2)